# SwiftUI ForEach "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate"

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I've been stuck on this for a good couple of days now trying to figure out what the issue is.

I have built a view which lists data which I can put in and save using core data.

My data model looks like so 
[image: Data Model]

I can add data to the list and read it all back without any issue, but when I try and filter the fetched results, I get the error that is in the title. The error is about half way down the code.

```
import CoreData


struct CollectionRow: View {
    var collectionDate = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    var body: some View {
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
            return Text(dateFormatter.string(from: collectionDate))
    }
}

struct CollectionList: View {

    var hospital = Hospital()

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Collection.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Collection.date, ascending: true)
        ]
    ) var collections: FetchedResults<Collection>

    @State private var collectionName = ""


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(collections, id: \.self) { collection in //Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate
                        if self.hospital.id == collection.hospital {
                            NavigationLink(destination: CollectionRow(collectionDate: Date())){
                                CollectionRow(collectionDate: Date())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    TextField("Test", text: $collectionName)
                    Button(action: {
                        let col = Collection(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                        col.date = Date()
                        col.id = Int16(self.collections.endIndex + 1)
                        col.hospital = self.hospital.id

                        self.hospital.addToHospToCol(col)

                        do {
                            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }

                        self.collectionName = ""
                    }) {
                        Text("New Collection")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text((hospital.name ?? "") + " - " + String(hospital.id)))
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The official tutorial uses an if statement inside a ForEach, so why can't I?

```
ForEach(landmarkData) { landmark in
                    if !self.showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite {
                        NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                            LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I filter an array in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926183/how-can-i-filter-an-array-in-swiftui)

Comment: The error messages in SwiftUI tend to be a bit random. My advice would be to comment out bits of your code until you get a meaningful error. My intuition is that you should make Collection conform to Identifiable and then declare ForEach(collections)

Comment: On second look it’s the whole ForEach that is wrong. ForEach in SwiftUI is not the forEach you know from collections. In SwiftUI it is used to construct list while I think you are using it to filter out an element. Am I right? Are you trying to show one link only for a hospital with matching id?

Comment: Not a single one, just only matching ones. The official tutorial uses an if statement inside a ForEach to filter out results

Answer (score 3):

`if/else` in SwiftUI can only be used inside `@ViewBuilder` closures, hence the `ForEach` failing.

More about function builders [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9992cf3c11c2d5e0ea20bee98657d93902d5b174/proposals/XXXX-function-builders.md).

A simple solution would be to wrap your code like this:

```swift
struct ForEachBuilder<Content>: View where Content: View {

    private let content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        content
    }

}
```

And your `ForEach` would become:

```swift
ForEach(collections, id: \.self) { collection in 
    ForEachBuilder {
        if self.hospital.id == collection.hospital {
            // Your navigation link
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if if/else statements can only work inside @ViewBuilder statements, how can the official tutorial use a if statement in the same way as mine?

Comment: @Shuttleu could you please post a link to the tutorial?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input Section 5, Step 3

Comment: Same problem. In the tutorial probably no CoreData is used. But actually that shouldn't be a reason.